# 7-Zip & Java - how do I get the value of percentage completed?

Tags: java, compression, progress-bar, 7zip

I wrote a Java code that sends files for compression using LzmaAlone.java.

Sending one file is not a problem, but for sending numerous files I need some confirmation that the previous file finished compressing. I also need to create a progress bar for each file being compressed... How can I do it?

Thanks!

```
  Compressor c = new Compressor();
            try {
                c.compress(original, newfile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

.............

```
public void compress(String filename, String newPath) throws Exception {

        try {
            LzmaAlone.main(new String[]{ "e", filename, newPath});

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume main() returns when it has finished. I would create a progress bar on a per file basis.

Comment: main returns, but how does it help me?

Comment: and how can I create such a bar? thanks!

Comment: If you compress one file at a time, every time main() returns, you have compressed one more file.  There are many, many ways of producing a progress bar. I suggest you look at examples on the web to determine which one you want.